# SyBase: Creating a Unique Index Based on The Value of The Columns

Tags: database, indexing, sybase, unique

I want my table to prevent duplicate entries only if the value of `ColumnA` is equal to a certain value.

For example, let's say there are already two records in my `TableA( ColumnA, ColumnB, ColumnC )` with the values `( 0, 'Damage', 'Inc.')` and `( 1, 'Damage', 'Inc.')`.

I'd like my index to allow the insertion of another `( 0, 'Damage', 'Inc.')`, but prevent the insertion of another `( 1, 'Damage', 'Inc.')`. I want only one entry present with ColumnA=1, but there can be several duplicate entries with ColumnA=0. Is this possible?

I found that there are function-based indexes, but I couldn't fit them to work for the expression `ColumnA=1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can control this insertion with trigger.